# jquery masked edit for time

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Using [meioMask Plugin](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) is there any way to set up a mask so it will accept valid time in 24h or even better in 12h system?

```
$("#txtTime").setMask('time');
```

This plugin has a pre-defined 24h 'time' mask but it's not quite correct, so you can enter invalid time values like "29:00". Is this mask is not suitable for this purpose and if not which one would be better?

Comment: you might want to try the plugin that started it all: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: One caveat: Please make sure to validate the value server side if it's at all important, otherwise people can hack together custom forms or query strings to bypass the restriction.

Comment: Not a sensitive information, time rarely is

Comment: +1 to Victor for sounding like the Doctor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.mask.rules.H = /([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])/;  // 24 hours
$.mask.masks.time = 'H:59';
$("#txtTime").setMask('time');
```

**Correction**:

The rules need to be for one character only, so having that in mind, you can swap the mask when the input starts with '2' and validate the next char to be [0-3]:

```
$("#txtTime").setMask("29:59")
.keypress(function() {
  var currentMask = $(this).data('mask').mask;
  var newMask = $(this).val().match(/^2.*/) ? "23:59" : "29:59";
  if (newMask != currentMask) {
    $(this).setMask(newMask);
  }
});
```

*Note*: In this case i'm using the keypress event, make sure to handle the paste event if needed.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Looks like this is a step in a right direction, but as it is doesn't accept any input at all:-)

Comment: I see, it seems like the meioMask plugin use a per char validation, I'll check if it allows multi-char rules.

Comment: It's all good except it won't allow some valid inputs that have 2 in them like I tried "23:32", won't let me input last "2"

Comment: I'll change the regex match to ^2.*

Comment: With that, works great, the only thing I had to change is to handle keydown event instead, or after 3rd number it just moves cursor over 1 left, don't know why.

Comment: In the last edit I fixed only changing the mask when needed, btw it's also a performance improvement too ;-)

Comment: there is a problem since i can write time as 29:00

Comment: hi is there any way to show --:-- by default and fix for issue that it allows me to enter 21 only but if so it should show 21:00 as its value...