# Time Picker for mobile devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile-website

I am working in HTML5, CSS3 and using jQuery for my project. I need to have a time picker only - no date picker - for mobile devices like iPad, Galaxy etc. It should work with both touchscreen and non-touchscreen devices. I found one with a slider but it failed on mobile devices.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522880/time-picker-for-mobile-devices/5529521#5529521
thak you for your post! It is that I search 2 days! Big respect!

Answer (score 19):

Check out [DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox). I think it does exactly what you need:

[image: timepicker]

Answer (score 14):

I've found another one which looks quite good. It also has different styles for different platforms: [mobiscroll](http://mobiscroll.com)

[image: mobiscroll time picker]
[image: mobiscroll time picker ios]

Comment: beautiful, free and for all (major) platforms! Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @dav_i: it is open source, and [available on github](https://github.com/acidb/mobiscroll), so still free. A subscription just gives you premium support and some other features (which are not worth a monthly fee IMO).

Answer (score 5):

Im glad to tell you that there is no need for a third party plugin in order to get the time-picker functionality.

HTML5 has already a native time picker wich is very easy to implement:

```
<label for="timePicker1">Set Time:</label>
<input type="time" name="timePicker1" id="timePicker1" value="10:00">
```

Read and write the value is equally easy with jQuery:

```
var time = $('#timePicker1').val(); //<- Get value
$('#timePicker1').val("09:30");     //<- Set value
```

The value for either set/get is an string with format 'hh:mm'.

It works as intended on JQuery Mobile 1.4.2.

There is also another usefull HTML5 controls here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Regards.

Comment: Unfortunately not supported in all major browsers

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this jQuery Time Picker based on the existing Datepicker but for time only. Never tried it on a mobile device but I think it will work well.

You can try it at : http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker

Comment: Thanks for the help. but guys i need a time picker that can display and let user select time upto seconds. Please tell me whether the control u made is customizable as well.

Comment: Guys I need to show minutes and seconds from 0 to 59 to user.

Comment: Sorry it does not do that. Minutes and seconds level input would be huge or complicated. Maybe you need a customized numpad or something.

Comment: Hi,Yes, you are right. I found one solution pointing to masking of text field to allow only time. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259843/jquery-masked-edit-for-time

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem -- I tried out the first Jquery datepicker (includes timepickers) example:

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/cantipi

It works once on my iPhone but then fails to respond to further touch events.

Then I tried the second one: Calendrical

http://tobiascohen.com/demos/calendrical/

I could set the time and reset it on the iPhone. Did you try it?

You might also look at Sencha for the touch events and consider its timer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like jQuery mobile updated their date and time picker code recently. Have a look at the demos here (that may only work properly on a mobile device):
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/textinputs/

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a native timepicker rather than a bespoke one. Found this which works really well on Android 4.0+. I haven't tested yet on iOS.

http://bikasv.com/blog/2013/04/14/cordova-datepicker/

Comment: Hi, this plugin is created by me. I'd like to say that this plugin supports Android 2.3+, not just 4.0+. You can see it in action with this play store app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bikasv.cordovaPlugin.

Comment: Also to add, iOS is not supported at all by this plugin, not yet at least.