# allowing the : or . symbol in meiomask time mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using meioMask to mask a textbox used for a user entering a time, which works fine. It allows times up to 23:59

```
 $("[id$=txtTime]").setMask("29:59")
    .keypress(function() {
        var currentMask = $(this).data('mask').mask;
        var newMask = $(this).val().match(/^2.*/) ? "23:59" : "29:59";
        if (newMask != currentMask) {
            $(this).setMask(newMask);
        }

    });
```

I think some users will try and enter the `:` symbol when typing in the date, where using the mask it doesnt allow symbols and the user may not expect it to carry on once entering further numbers.

How can i allow the `:` or `.` symbols in the mask? I'm terrible at regex.

Thanks.

Comment: You can match an hour with . or : with `"(?:2[0-3]|1\d|0?\d)[\.:][0-6]\d"` is this what you want?

Comment: thanks but not exactly, i'm trying to get meiomask to allow me to enter : in the textbox

Comment: You copied some code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259843/jquery-masked-edit-for-time and now what? Do you know what you want? Because I don't get it. Try to clarify...

Comment: Thats right. I'm trying to allow the user to type the : key, the meiomask doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the rules to add the colon so it is recognized as a reserved item that can be editable.

```
$.mask.rules = {
  'z': /[a-z]/,
  'Z': /[A-Z]/,
  'a': /[a-zA-Z]/,
  '*': /[0-9a-zA-Z]/,
  '@': /[0-9a-zA-ZçÇáàãéèíìóòõúùü]/,
  ':': /[:]/
};
```

Worth a shot. I'm kinda shooting blind as I haven't tested that, but it may just work.

Answer (score -1):

Add rule similar as mentioned above: `':': /:/` and remove `:` from the string `options.fixedChars`